# Passed in Vue prop coming in as variable name, not as the string it represents

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The parent component which is passing down my string var 
The const `GET_STARTED` = the string `"Get Started"`

```
<script setup>
import { GET_STARTED } from '../../constants'
import GreenBtn from '@/components/partials/GreenBtn.vue'

console.log('GET_STARTED', GET_STARTED)
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <div class="moon-cta">
      <section class="tagline">
        <h1>The Bold Portfolio {{GET_STARTED}} Tracker For Brave Crypto Investors</h1>
        <h2>Start / continue your crypto investing journey with us.</h2>
        <GreenBtn copy={GET_STARTED} url='/sign-up' />
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
```

The partial child component

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['copy', 'url'])
const { copy, url } = props
console.log('props', props)

const handleGetStartedClick = (msg) => {
  console.log(msg)
  console.log(`Goto url: ${url}`)
}
</script>

<template>
  <button v-on:click="handleGetStartedClick(`${copy} clicked.`)">
    {{ copy }}
  </button>
</template>
```

^ above I expect copy to be the string value "Get Started"

**The result in the UI**

copy={GET_STARTED}
[image]

if I tried copy='GET_STARTED'
[image]

**Expected**

[image]

**My logs**

[image]

Any thoughts here? This seems like the correct way to pass down string vars in Vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from the VueJS discord

> **Bobakanoosh** —
> In order to pass variables, you do: `:copy="GET_STARTED"`
> the `:` is important, it tells vue to treat the thing you pass as javascript, not a string